How to overcome when staments in Kotlin
 Hey, 
I think that I am not the only Android and Kotlin developer who has an “allergy” to when statements. The simple reason is that these statements often easily grow into some ugly code. For example:
fun parseUserEvent(userEvent: UserEvent) {
    when (userEvent) {
        is UserEvent.A -> doSomething()
        is UserEvent.B -> doSomethingElse()
        is UserEvent.C -> doAnotherThing()
        is UserEvent.D -> doSomethingDifferent()
            // and so on
    }
}

My solution to this problem is to use explicit callbacks, which force me, each time a new event is added, to think if it’s appropriate to add it to the existing event or to consider another design. For example:
fun onUserIconClicked(event: UserIconsEvent) {
        event
            .onPersonalAreaClicked {
                // handle personal area click
            }
            .onFavoritesClicked {
                // handle favorites click
            }
            .onOrdersClicked {
                // handle orders click
            }
    }

where
fun UserIconsEvent.onPersonalAreaClicked(action: () -> Unit): UserIconsEvent {
    if (this is UserIconsEvent.OnPersonalAreaClicked) {
        action()
    }
    return this
}

Are there any other approaches to avoid “unlimited when” code blocks?

I would say it's the opposite. when and similar utils in other languages were invented, so we don't have to use solutions like your chain of function calls. when is cleaner and potentially better for the performance. Alternatively, if you have a lot of different events, you add more with time, then you can approach this with the classic OOP: add an abstract function to events, and then each of them implements the logic whatever they like.

I don't know exactly how do the conditional statements work in Kotlin under the hood, but it seems like additional complexity is the if, which sounds logically to me that the same check will be in the when block, or doesn't it ?

I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Are you referring to what I said about potential difference in the performance?

Yes. You said that when has better performance

I said "potentially better performance". First, in your solution we have to call a lot of functions, with when we remain in a single function. Second, when is clear about the fact we choose between multiple disjoint cases, your solution simply executes a lot of sequential ifs. For example, I believe when for enums is constant time, your solution would be linear. It is more tricky with checking is, but potentially there is still a room for optimization. In practice and with JIT optimizations, I assume both solutions are the same or the difference is negligible.

One of the problems with the when is that you have to break the open–closed principle (OCP) when adding a new event.
A solution might be to define individual actions in the events themselves:
interface Event {
    fun action(): void;
}

class AEvent: Event {
    fun action(): void {
        // logic for the event
    }
}

class BEvent: Event {
    fun action(): void {
        // logic for the event
    }
}

// etc.

…
fun handle(Event event): void {
   event.action();
}
…

And the logic of working with Even will be simplified to: event.action() without using the when construct, since you no longer need to know the logic of event processing, it now knows what to do.

How do I know when to use this variation of Composite Design Pattern as a replacement for when and when it becomes overkill ?

@NickSahno added few lines to code snippet. It’s not Composite Design Pattern. I would always use a similar approach, because firstly I want to have smaller class sizes (your functions doSomething, doSomethingElse ... are defined somewhere, I suspect in the same place as when), secondly I don't want to make changes to the tested classes when expanding possible events.

The problem with your solution accures when each event need properties of ViewModel class, state update for example. How do you suggest to connect the VM class, where event.action() is called ?

I came with this answer, which is more functional programming rather than OOP 
// Handler.kt
class HandleEvents(
    val onEventA: () -> Unit = {},
    val onEventB: (String) -> Unit = {},
    // etc
)

// ViewModel.kt
val handleEvents = HandleEvents(
    onEventA = {
        updateEventA()
    },
    onEventB = { data ->
        updateEventB(data)
    },
)

// Foo.kt
@Composable
fun Foo(handleEvents: HandleEvents) {
    // ...
    handleEvents.onEventA()
    // ...
    
    
    handleEvents.onEventB("someData")
    // ...
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
